# How to look up user information from Google GAIA ID?

Tags: php, android, json, google-hangouts

I've been working on a Hangouts.json parser for Google's Takeout service that takes all of the conversations, attachments, and miscellaneous information from the json file and populates a database with everything. I've finished everything but the only information the json file provides for who sent what is a GAIA ID that I've been able to figure out is the unique ID Google uses between their services. The problem is I don't know how to look up any other information about the user such as the name they identify with or their email.

I know most of the information is publicly available as you can take the GAIA ID and put it into a URL like: `https://plus.google.com/u/0/#####################/about` where the #'s are the GAIA ID. This page will reveal their screen name publicly. When a email address is unknown the same thing can be inferred by using: `reply-#####################@profiles.google.com` where this will also be able to be used to contact them.

Ideally I'd like to be able to look up a user's screen name without having to parse that public Google+ page at least but a true email would be great as well. So ideally I'd like an API or other resource to look up screen names and / or email info from a GAIA ID.

Comment: For the record, GAIA stands for _Google Accounts and ID Administration_: https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/70/admin_console_help/cloud_google_apps.html

Comment: I was also toying with `Hangouts.json` file from Google Takeout, and created java/kotlin parser at https://github.com/amardeshbd/kotlin-google-hangouts-parser - this is good information for experimenting more with the data snapshot. I can confirm `https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get` works to get user profile info.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have exactly same goal - get email from gaia Id. I have feedbacks under offline commerce in Google maps from the users. I can get gaia id only from "local experts" or gmap and haven't possibility to resolve users problems if they have or improve loyalty of them. I'm not sure if reply-#####################@profiles.google.com address works properly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**

March 2019: This answer is still getting up votes, however Google are withdrawing / have withdrawn the Google Plus API.

You will need an alternative solution as this will no longer apply.

**Original Reply**

Use the Google Plus API: https://developers.google.com/+/api/

I've not tested specifically with Hangouts (I never knew there was a Hongouts API!) but it returns details given IDs from other APIs.

You can test it out here: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.get to see what you'll get.

Answer (score 5):

The **Gaia ID** may be obtained with the **[People API](https://developers.google.com/people/)**, by requesting the `metadata` in  the `personFields`.

You may try it with the [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) (sample links are provided below).

---

**For any of your contacts** (provided he/she is a google user), using the `people.connections/list` resource :

[People API - people.connections/list - personFields=names,metadata](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list?apix_params=%7B%22resourceName%22%3A%22people%2Fme%22%2C%22personFields%22%3A%22names%2Cmetadata%22%7D)
(I have included the `names` value in the `personFields` for better illustration, though it is not required to retrieve the Gaia Id)

Sample output (`1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` is the Gaia Id):

```
{
  "connections": [
    {
      "resourceName": "people/c42",
      "etag": "...",
      "metadata": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "type": "CONTACT",
            ...
          },
          {
            "type": "PROFILE",
            "id": "1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            ...
            "profileMetadata": {
              "objectType": "PERSON",
              "userTypes": [
                "GOOGLE_USER"
              ]
            }
          }
          ....
        ],
        "objectType": "PERSON"
      }
      "names": [
        {
          ...
          "displayName": "John Doe",
          ...
        }
      ]
    },
    ...
}
```

---

**For yourself or any user** using the `people/get` resource

[People API - people/get - personFields=metadata](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get?apix_params=%7B%22resourceName%22%3A%22people%2Fme%22%2C%22personFields%22%3A%22metadata%22%7D)

In the `resourceName` field :

- use `people/me` to obtain your informations.
- use the `resourceName` value previously retrieved in a `people.connections.list` request to retrieve another user informations

Sample output (`1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` is the Gaia Id):

```
{
  "resourceName": "people/...",
  "etag": "....",
  "metadata": {
    "sources": [
      {
        "type": "PROFILE",
        "id": "1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "etag": "...",
        "profileMetadata": {
          "objectType": "PERSON",
          "userTypes": [
            "GOOGLE_USER"
          ]
        }
        ...
      },
     ...
    ],
    "objectType": "PERSON"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to google chat.
create a chat with the person you want to find gaia id.
tag the person in the chat window
(@name of person)
right click the name, click "Inspect"

There you will find the ID
data-user-id="10xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

@Name of person