# Direct link to Google Chat DM

Tags: google-hangouts

I'm unable to generate a direct link to Google Chat DM. We'd like to link Google Chat DMs to peoples profiles in our organisation.

I've tried to use the users Google ID to generate the link, for example `https://chat.google.com/dm/123455` but that redirects nowhere.

I'd expect that there is a way to generate a direct link, either by using users primary email, google ID or to list users DMs through an API call.

Comment: I just created a new feature request, for the Google Hangouts Chat API (or People API for that matter), to expose this information : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134526655 Go and star it to vote ! :)

Comment: Nick Dunn's answer should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Retrieving the "user chat ID" does not seems possible with the existing API.
I have created a new feature request, for the Google Hangouts Chat API (or People API for that matter), to expose this information : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134526655

As a workaround, you can use the People API to retrieve the Gaia ID of a user, and then open the a Google Hangouts conversation with the appropriate URL.
 Quoting [my answer to "Create direct link to Google Hangouts chat"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/130466/205279) :

> 1. you'll need to know that person's Gaia ID (an internal ID used by Google).
>
>    I have added [a detailed answer to an existing stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56442288/64556) in which I describe **how to retrieve the Gaia ID using the [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/)**.
>      TL;DR: Request `metadata` in the `personFields`, by using `people.connections.list` resources for your contacts, or the `people/get` resource for yourself.
> 2. Once you've got someone's Gaia ID, it's pretty straightforward to create the correct URL to start a Hangout with them. Simply replace 1XXXXXXXXXXXX below with that user's Gaia ID:
>
>    https://hangouts.google.com/chat/person/1XXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: Per your step 2, is there an equivalent link for Google Chat? Hangouts has been disabled by my administrator. I tried various forms of https://chat.google.com/ but they all redirect as being incorrectly formed.

Comment: Same issue here, I cannot find an equivalent for Google Chat. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the direct message URL required is specific to the two users involved. The link isn't to userA - it's to the chat between userA and userB

In the Google workspace environment With a bit of shennanigans you can find those links or create them for two users.

It involves using a service account with domain-wide delegation. Then you can impersonate one user to find the direct_message link from them to another user. If none exists then you can create it.

I've detailed those shenanigans in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56891280/create-a-direct-link-to-open-a-conversation-with-a-user-at-chat-google-com/78002234#78002234)